# How to writephp script to send reminder email to user before 5 days of deadline?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, email-notifications

I have written a mail function in codeigniter (PHP) to send mail to users. Now I want to send a reminder mail 5 days before their expire date. If anybody have any idea please post here...

Answer (score 2):

Create a cron job (or scheduled task if you use Windows) to run your script and run it every day / hour (or any other timeframe that suits your needs).
There are plenty of tutorials on google how to setup cron job, [check this out](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) for example